# Is there any python package to clean or predict OCR result?

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

I have been trying to read some scanned documents using Tesseract OCR. Most of the documents are not clear so, I am getting some garbage values within the strings. for example,

*Actual Output:*
date field: **16/02M9**, decimal field: **7,223. .95C**

*Expected Output:*
date field: **16/02/19**, decimal field: **7,223.950**

These are the only few examples, I am facing more issues like these. So, is there any library that can clean or predict the correct value based on given data type like date, numeric, etc.

Comment: There is no library for that, however, if we knew the data that you want to read (are these dates on ID documents, or utility bills?), there might be libraries for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the documents first as suggested on this page:

https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality

One of the tools mentioned there that might help:

http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/textcleaner/index.php